# CSS Box Shadow - Hover Class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a generic hover class that uses box-shadow amd that will work with multiple colors of buttons. For this reason, I want the "shadow" to be different for every color of button. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to use or set only the color attribute of a shadow element?

Here is what I mean:

```
/*Notice that .button shadows does not have a color value*/

.button {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
    0px 8px 16px 0px;
    box-shadow:
    0px 8px 16px 0px;
}

.button:hover{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
    0px 16px 16px 0px;
    box-shadow:
    0px 16px 16px 0px;
}

/*And color elements does not have other values for the shadow*/

.red{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow:
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.green{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
    rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow:
    rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}
```

...to be used as follows:

```
<div class="button red>Red Button</div>
<div class="button green>Green Button</div>
```

I hope that explains the situation. Brainstorm time!

Comment: You don't need to specify `-webkit-` anymore, unless you need to support Android and old iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `color: red`

```
.red{
    color:red
}
.green{
   color:green
}
```

Since `color:` property applies to the text also, you need to wrap the text with `span` tag and give `color:black` to `span`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jLXZ9/)**

Comment: Oh wait, is this a "buggy" situation, or is this how it's supposed to work?! This might be a solution for me but looks quite cheesy.

Comment: @Zettam: The spec contradicts itself; it says "the color is UA-chosen", but it *also* says "the color is taken from the `color` property if not specified on the shadow" (which is what's happening here). I'm going to email the CSSWG to ask...

Comment: @Sowmya: There is no such thing as `box-shadow-color`.

Comment: @Zettam: OK, I was right - "the color is taken from `color`" was *not* in the spec [two years ago](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-css3-background-20110215); it was a recent addition. It looks like all browsers have been updated to this, so it should be reliable. That said, the "UA-chosen" part is still in the spec which may be confusing. I've [emailed](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Feb/0204.html) the working group now.

Comment: @Zettam: It's [confirmed](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Feb/0208.html) - it's definitely how it's supposed to work, and you can rely on it as long as you don't need to support older browsers (i.e. browsers released more than 1 year ago).

Comment: Hum, that is kind of good news though.  still have one issue with this method: How can I set the shadow color of each shadow layer on a single element?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to specify ONLY the color for a box shadow as specified here: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#the-box-shadow

You will need to give a separate box shadow rule for each color class.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3 there in no box-shadow-color rule, so for different buttons you need to specify all shadow  parameters (size, position, color).

Answer (score 0):

try this css styles in this style using color for individual menu, u can try shadow to set instead of color...

HTMl Code

```
<div class="menu"> 
        <ul>
            <li class="active1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS Style

```
.menu{
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color:white;
        float:left;
        position:absolute;  
        top:95px;
        width:855px;
        background-image:url(../images/bottom-menu-line.png);
        background-position:center bottom;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
    .menu ul{padding:0; margin-left:65px; border-radius:10px;}
    .menu ul li {
        float:left;
        border-radius:10px;
        width:110px;
        height:47px;
        list-style:none;
        padding:0;
        margin-left:5px;
        margin-right:5px;
        /*overflow:hidden*/
    }
    .menu ul li a {
        font-size:12px;
        color:#fffcc7;
        background-image:url(../images/button.png);
        background-position:center;
        height:47px;
        overflow:hidden;
        line-height:47px;
        text-decoration:none;
        width:110px;
        text-align:center;
        float:left;
        border-radius:10px;
    }
    .menu li {float:left; padding:0;}
    .menu ul li a:hover {
     margin: -3px;
    }
    .menu ul li:nth-of-type(6) a:hover {
     border:3px solid #c10202 !important;
     border-radius:10px !important;
    }
    .menu ul li:nth-of-type(5) a:hover {
    border:#c1d65f solid 3px;
    border-radius:10px;
    }
    .menu ul li:nth-of-type(4) a:hover {
    border:#01d290 solid 3px;
    border-radius:10px;
    }
    .menu ul li:nth-of-type(3) a:hover {
    border:#904ca1 solid 3px;
    border-radius:10px;
    }
    .menu ul li:nth-of-type(2) a:hover {
    border:#00caf3 solid 3px;
    border-radius:10px;
    }
    .menu ul li:nth-of-type(1) a:hover {
    border:3px #d44c1f solid;
    border-radius:10px;
    }
    .active1{
    border:3px #d44c1f solid;   
    width:110px !important;
    border-radius:10px;
    height:47px !important;
    margin-bottom:7px !important;
    margin-right:5px !important;
    }
    .active2{
    border:#00caf3 solid 3px;   
    width:110px !important;
    border-radius:10px;
    height:47px !important;
    margin-bottom:7px !important;
    margin-right:5px !important;
    }
    .active3{
    border:#904ca1 solid 3px;   
    width:110px !important;
    border-radius:10px;
    height:47px !important;
    margin-bottom:7px !important;
    margin-right:5px !important;
    }
    .active4{
    border:#01d290 solid 3px;   
    width:110px !important;
    border-radius:10px;
    height:47px !important;
    margin-bottom:7px !important;
    margin-right:5px !important;
    }
    .active5{
    border:#c1d65f solid 3px;   
    width:110px !important;
    border-radius:10px;
    height:47px !important;
    margin-bottom:7px !important;
    margin-right:5px !important;
    }
    .active6{
    border:3px solid #c10202;   
    width:110px !important;
    border-radius:10px;
    height:47px !important;
    margin-bottom:7px !important;
    margin-right:5px !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, you have to put the 2 cases normal and hover for each button

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#the-box-shadow